# How to mock generative types using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock this method:

```
public async Task<List<T>> MyMethod<T>(string string1, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string string2) where T : IMyModel, new() {}
```

Keep in mind I don't have permission to change how the method is written, I only need to mock it for a call I'm making elsewhere.

I've tried usint `It.IsAny<>` but that doesn't seem to work for generative types:

```
object result = this.myMock
    .Setup(mock => mock.MyMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new List<MyModel> { myModelInstance });
```

for the code above, I'd get this error:

[image]

Comment: Presumably explicitly use the generic type so mock `MyMethod<MyModel>(It. ...`

Comment: @Ralf although this doesn't complain about any syntax errors, it doesn't do the mocking correctly. When running the test it fails to match this instance of MyMethod to the one being run and the mocking doesn't end up happening at all.

Comment: The syntax is correct but for the problem we need to understand the actual call in the actual code and the test call on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can mock your MyMethod using Moq:

```
// Create a mock instance of your interface
var myMock = new Mock<YourInterface>();

// Mock the MyMethod with generative types
myMock.Setup(mock => mock.MyMethod<MyModel>(
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(),
    It.IsAny<string>()
)).ReturnsAsync(new List<MyModel> { myModelInstance });

// Use the mocked object in your test
YourInterface mockObject = myMock.Object;
```

Comment: although this doesn't complain about any syntax errors, it doesn't do the mocking correctly. When running the test it fails to match this instance of MyMethod to the one being run and the mocking doesn't end up happening at all.